# Stuck while pulling from the master branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

It seems that all my `git pull` and `git push` command are stuck.

I have created an private repository on bitbucket and created a readMe online. After that, I tried to pull it to my local repository via `git pull`, however I got stuck while running git pull, like this:

[image: "git pull" got stuck]

I don't know why it happened. Could anyone help, thanks.

============================================

P.S. I was using mac

Comment: Go into your repository directory and try to make it in console mode `git pull` and you will have your answer.

Comment: close terminal and retry! it happens sometime

Comment: What does it mean by "making it in console mode". I am using mac, do you mean that I need to restart the computer and enter into "another mode"?